# Syntax Error: unexpected Token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, routes

Here is my Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var partySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  partyCode: Number,
  partyName: String,
  mobileNo: String
});

var Party = module.exports = mongoose.model('Party', partySchema);

module.exports.getAllParties = function(callback){
  Party.find().lean().exec(function(err, parties){
    if (err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, parties);
  });
};
```

Here is the Route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

  //retrieve all parties from Party model
  //mongoose.model('Party').find({}, function (err, parties) {
  Party.getAllParties(err, parties){
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } else {
            //respond to both HTML and JSON. JSON responses require 'Accept: application/json;' in the Request Header
            res.format({

              //response in dust or jade files
              html: function(){
                  res.render('Party', {
                        title: 'Party',
                        "parties" : parties
                    });
              },

              //JSON response will show all parties in JSON format
              json: function(){
                  res.json(parties);
              }
          });
        }
  };
});
```

At line no 9 in Route.js (Here in above code line no.4) I get an error:

```
  Party.getAllParties(err, parties){
```

**Syntax error: {unexpected token**

Why is it unexpected? Can't I use a function's body here???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a function instead. A block statement like that outside unfortunately won't work.

This is most likely what you need:

```
Party.getAllParties(function (err, parties) {  
    // rest of your logic here
});
```

Comment: I have tried to execute as you said, but then in browser I get an error saying that Party is not defined. As well as  in command prompt I get error: Unhandled Rejection error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't place a block statement these when you're calling a function.

It looks like you want something like

```
Party.getAllParties(function() {
    // ...
})
```

Where you pass an anonomous callback function

Comment: I have tried to execute as you said, but then in browser I get an error saying that Party is not defined. As well as in command prompt I get error: Unhandled Rejection error: Can't set headers after they are sent.